# Pandas: most efficient way to access file from s3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, boto

I want to load large csv files(~100-500mb) stored in s3 to pandas dataframe. The code is running in a docker container inside an ec2 instance. I see three approaches to access the data

1. Download the file to local file system and then use padas.read_csv(path_to_file) like

```
aws_object = boto3.resource('s3', 
                            "useast1",
                            aws_access_key_id='xxxx',
                            aws_secret_access_key= 'xxx')
aws_object.Bucket(s3_bucket).download_file(s3_key,download_folder+os.sep+file_name)
```

2. Read the file as stream

```
aws_object = boto3.resource('s3',
                            "useast1",
                            aws_access_key_id='xxxx',
                            aws_secret_access_key='xxx')

csv_string = s3_object['Body'].read()

df_head = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(csv_string),
                      encoding="ISO-8859-1",
                      nrows=5,
                      header=None)
```

3. Read the file directly from s3 path

```
data = pd.read_csv('s3:/bucket....csv')
```

What are the pros and cons of each methods? Which is the recommended approach ? Is downloading file to local file system more efficient? I might need to load the file few times into separate dataframes while processing the file.

Comment: You should probably measure all three approaches to see what's fastest.

Comment: 500mb isn't particularly large so each method is likely to give similar results. If it were me I'd choose `3` because it's the simplest for the next person to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

1. Downloading the csv will make a copy to your local storage, a pro to this is that you could make in-place edits to the files if necessary and it will be faster on the back-end to access. Plus, since the copy is local you will not need an internet connection to play with the data. The obvious con is that over time you will use a lot of storage.
2. Streaming has the obvious benefit of accessing the data remotely so you do not use up your own storage. Cons are that it is slower than accessing a downloaded file because it will rely on the speed of your internet, as well as it will constantly be using bandwidth to look at files. This just means that over time, if you run this program on multiple files at once the bandwidth will stack up quickly, and could make some other internet users angry.
3. Reading the file directly from the S3 path will probably be your best bet. This will store the data as a pandas dataframe in memory and only access the data once (to store it). Then all further changes to the dataframe will be applied to the object in memory.

The best method will depend on your downstream applications. I do not think downloading the csv file will ever be the most practical method, because your code is pointing to the s3 bucket. The only practical purpose of downloading the data would be to access it without internet (in which case you would download the file outside of the code and then access it from your local pc).

Your code 2 and 3 are redundant. When you are streaming the data that is fine, but then you are loading it as a dataframe object anyway, which kind of defeats the purpose of reading the file as a stream. The amount of data in the dataframe will be the same because you're storing it eventually. I think METHOD 3, will be your best bet because it takes away that unnecessary redundancy.